# Algorithm for least cost image segmentation

Tags: image, algorithm, graph-algorithm

Im having a hard time trying to figure an algorithm to solve the problem of image segmentation with min-cost. The cost of the image is calculated this way:

The weight of the pixels in the first plan + the weight of the pixels on the second plan + weight of the edges that connect pixels from different plans. (If 2 pixels are on the same plan, we dont count the cost of the edge that connects them)

The input to my problem follows this pattern:

Two Numbers.First number referes to number of lines, second number refers to number of columns

```
5 5
```

The **weights of the pixels** on the first plan(P):

```
8 7 9 9 7
6 2 2 8 7
9 1 2 1 8
2 1 3 1 7
1 3 2 1 9
```

The **weights of the pixels** on the second plan(C):

```
2 1 2 3 2
1 9 9 1 3
1 7 7 9 3
8 7 9 7 2
7 9 8 9 1
```

The **weights of the edges** that connect the pixels horizontally.

```
8 9 7 6
1 9 0 8
1 8 9 2
8 7 9 1
9 8 7 2
```

The **weight of the edges** that connect the pixels vertically.

```
8 2 1 7 9
7 8 7 1 8
2 8 7 7 8
9 7 8 9 8
```

The objective is to find the segmentation with the least cost and to return a matrix that shows which pixels belong to the first and second plan.

Output for this case:

```
57

C C C C C 
C P P C C 
C P P P C 
P P P P C 
P P P P C
```

[Image that represents the problem:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUpGC.png)

[Here is an image that shows why the answer is this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhpIi.png)

In my classes my teachers told us that Edmund-Karps will solve this problem but i cant see how to model this problem in one where we are suppoose to find the max flux.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic max-flow problem. Treat every pixel as a node. Create two new nodes `S` and `T`. For every pixel `x`, add a directed edge `(S, x)` with cost equal to the weight of `x` in (P). Similarly, add a directed edge `(x, T)` with cost equal to the weight of `x` in (C). Finally, add bidirectional edges between adjacent pixels, using the weights of edges given.

Then, you can show that any `S`-`T` cut in this graph corresponds to an image segmentation. In particular, there are 3 kinds of edges in such a cut:

- Edges between `S` and a pixel `x`, which correspond to putting `x` in plane (P)
- Edges between a pixel `x` and `T`, which correspond to putting `x` in plane (C)
- Edges between two pixels `x` and `y`, which correspond to edges between planes.

Hence, the min-cut in this graph precisely corresponds to the best image segmentation.

By the min cut max flow theorem, the min cut can be found using a max flow algorithm such as Edmonds-Karp.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But in this case wont the BFS paths contain only 2 edges? from S to x and x to  Y? And whenever i find one of theses paths